# React changing input value to another input value using if condition error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-state

I am using react and I am trying to change the value of an input to another input using an if conditon. I am encountering an error where the input value changes to the previous value and not the current one. Example: I enter 1 in input1 and input2 stays blank. Then I add a 0 to input1 making the value 10, the second input then changes its value to 1. I then delete the 0 from input 1 making the value once again 1 and the second input changes to 10.

I am using useState here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function () {
    const [select1, setSelect1] = useState("test")
    const [input1, setInput1] = useState("")
    const [input2, setInput2] = useState("")

    function select1Function(e) {
        setInput1(e.target.value)
        if (select1 === "test") {
            setInput2(input1)
            document.getElementById("input2").disabled = true
        } else {
            document.getElementById("input2").disabled = false
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>

            <select value={select1} onChange={e => setSelect1(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="test">Test</option>
                    <more options here (irrelevant to question)>
            </select>

            <input type="number" value={input1} onChange={select1Function}></input>
            <input type="number" value={input2} onChange={e => setInput2(e.target.value)} id="input2"></input>

        </div>
    )
}
```

The value of input2 is on a one character delay and I cant figure out why. I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `setState` isn't synchronous. It creates a "pending state transition." (See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more details). You should explicitly pass the new input value as part of the event being raised.

Your code should be:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function () {
    const [select1, setSelect1] = useState("test")
    const [input1, setInput1] = useState("")
    const [input2, setInput2] = useState("")

    function select1Function(e) {
        setInput1(e.target.value)
        if (select1 === "test") {
            setInput2(e.target.value)
            document.getElementById("input2").disabled = true
        } else {
            document.getElementById("input2").disabled = false
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>

            <select value={select1} onChange={e => setSelect1(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="test">Test</option>
                    <more options here (irrelevant to question)>
            </select>

            <input type="number" value={input1} onChange={select1Function}></input>
            <input type="number" value={input2} onChange={e => setInput2(e.target.value)} id="input2"></input>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I just have one more question. When I change the select option from test to something else how do I get it to un-disable? I changed the option value and the input stayed disabled.

Comment: You'll have to create a separate function to handle the select onChange. Right now you're checking for `input1` change only.